# Know if user is online using Swift and Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3

I'm currently coding a messenger into my socialApp.
I would like to know if the person I am talking to is online.

First, it could permits me to show if the user is online or not:

[image]

And then, I could permits me to don't send push notification (because the user is in the chat).

I thought to create a simple child in the database (something like:

```
isOnline
|_User1
   |__User2: true
```

Now, my problem is I don't know how to toggle the value.

- If the user come to the page -> set true (OK)
- If the user clic on back button -> remove the value (OK)
- when user leave the app (even in background) -> remove the value (Not ok)

Is is the good way to process?

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/offline-capabilities#how-ondisconnect-works)?

Comment: @AndréKool I don't know how to do this: when user leave the app (even in background) -> remove the value (Not ok)

Comment: @KevinB check out ApplicationDelegate function: ```applicationWillResignActive```. This gets called right before application goes to background.

Comment: Hi Kevin. Please refrain from adding "thanks in advance" and other chatty material here - I have removed quite a lot of that from your post history! Thank you. (There's several references on Meta, [but here's one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288160)).

Answer (score 3):

You can use **applicationWillResignActive** And **applicationDidBecomeActive** in *AppDelegate* to notify if user is online :

```
func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
        // user is offline 
        let ref = Database.database().reference.child("isOnline").child(user)
        ref.setValue(false) // NO
    }

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
        let ref = Database.database().reference.child("isOnline").child(user)
        ref.setValue(true) // YES
}
```

Comment: My code works for applicationWillResignActive. I use a global variable to stock the user ID. But, How can I do to know in applicationDidBecomeActive, if the user is well on the chat view controller ?

Comment: @KevinB you want the user to be online only if the user in chat view controller ?